# Generic Interface with TDelegate as an event?

Tags: c#, events, .net-3.5

I am trying to create this simple interface. I want it somehow to be able to fire an event.
This is what I have till now (doesn't compile, just my thoughts)

```
public interface IAsyncSearch<TTermType, TResultsEventType>
                                                 where TResultsEventType:delegate
{
    event TResultsEventType SearchCompletedEvent;
    void SearchAsync(TTermType term);
}
```

Is something similar even possible? I know that a type is expected in the where statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public interface IAsyncSearch<TData, TArgs>
{
    event EventHandler<SpecialDataEventArgs<TArgs>> SearchCompletedEvent;
    void SearchAsync(TData term);
}

public class SpecialDataEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public SpecialDataEventArgs(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public T Data { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Or maybe just use `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` while constraining `TEvenetArgs : EventArgs`.

Comment: My solution is for the case when there is alot of params

Answer (score 2):

All event types ought to derive from EventHandler<>, the standard .NET event handler type.  Helps anybody that reads your code recognize it quickly.  And even more appropriate here, it readily solves your problem:

```
    public interface IAsyncSearch<TTermType, TResultsArgType> 
        where TResultArgType : EventArgs 
    {
        event EventHandler<TResultsArgType> SearchCompletedEvent;
        void SearchAsync(TTermType term);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Events work only with delegate types. And there is no way to constrain type parameter to be a delegate in C#. Because of that, I don't think what you want is possible in C#.

[According to Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/09/10/generic-constraints-for-enums-and-delegates.aspx), it actually may be possible to do this in CIL, so maybe if you wrote that type in CIL, you could be able to use it from C# the way you want.

**EDIT:** You can create such type in CIL, but it seems you can't use it property from C#. It seems you can't implement it. And calling the event methods using `+=` doesn't work either. But calling them using the `add_SearchCompletedEvent` does work.